# Return value from include on a remote file

Tags: php, include, return, remote-server

I am trying to run a script on a remote server, and have the results of that script returned to the calling script. A variable is sent to the remote script, and based on that the remote script is meant to retrieve a list of filenames on the remote server, and return those filenames as an array. However, using return in the included file is not returning an actual value, it just aborts the script. Other than that, the remote script runs without a problem, and I can have it var_dump the list of filenames for me, but that doesn't do much good for me on the local script. Both servers are owned by us (us being my company).

I've tried something simple like this just to see if I could get a return value and it didn't work:

Local Script:

```
$test = include "http://remote_host_address/remote_script.php";  
var_dump($test);
```

Remote Script:

```
$ret = "Hello World";
return $ret;
```

This outputs `int(1)`. The code itself of the remote script works perfectly, that I've tested, and the variable I send as a get variable also goes through no problem. The only problem is that I am not getting a return value from the remote_script.

Also, yes `allow_url_include` is on for the local server. However, it is off for the remote server; but that should not make a difference: http://php.net/allow-url-include.

I have looked over some of the other related questions on this topic, and nothing seems to quite describe my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have spent a few hours looking this over already and have not made any progress.

Comment: This is a bad practice and should be avoided. Anyway, @Glavić solution will probably work. You're remote including a php file. That means that the http wrapper will ask the remote server to execute the php file and the include will try **afterwards** to include (meaning execute locally) its output. The output here is nothing here as your distant script doesn't echo anything. Thus include returns "1", meaning it successfully included the empty output.

Comment: @Kethryweryn - Good practice or not, I won't argue. In any case, I've tried having my remote script echo/var_dump, and it does print to screen, but it does not affect the return value of the include statement. Also, Glavic's solution technically works in that it runs the script, but then the script is run locally; I want it to run on the remote server to retrieve the file list. If there is another way to accomplish this, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of include.
This writes the file into a variable [causing the script to execute remotely], but won't run the response locally.

Alternatively If you have the ability to [use cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), it is safer and probably quicker.
A small snippet to remotely file_get_contents();

```
function curl_get_contents($url){
    $c = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $res = curl_exec($c);
    if (curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) > 400) $res = false;
    curl_close($c);
    return $res;
    }
```

By way of explanation

- RETURNTRANSFER puts the response of the curl request into a variable (instead of printing to screen).
- CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION has not been set, so if the page has been moved, curl will not follow it. You can set that, or have it set based on a second argument.
- HTTP_CODE, if above 400 (an err code, presumably 404 or 500) will return false instead of the fancy custom 404 page that might be setup.
  In my testing, [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) is more reliable than curlinfo_http_code but requires a second call to the page being included, which can make things go awry.
  eg. `if (!strpos(200, get_headers($url)[0])) return false;`

Comment: Here you go. Good practice, and +1.

Comment: I use file_get_contents() with GET using md5 hashes, like checkUser.php?user=21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3. So, the idea is use a plain html response (like 0/1 or hash) to ensure comunication safety.

Nevermind to display php code!!!

Answer (score 0):

Script on other server `http://remote_host_address/remote_script.php` is probably being executed. Rename file to `.txt` and then use `include` on that file.

---

If the script must be run remotely, then run it, and return/echo php code. Example:

File: **`http://localhost/test.php`**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$array = array();
// your logic
$array['remote_server_time'] = time();
$array['sub'] = array(1, 2, 3);
// etc.

//output
echo '<?php return ' . var_export($array, true) . ';';
```

will output:

```
<?php return array (
  'remote_server_time' => 1381401586,
  'sub' => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
  ),
);
```

File: **`http://localhost/index.php`**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$array = include('http://localhost/test.php');
print_r($array);
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [remote_server_time] => 1381401701
    [sub] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )
)
```

Comment: Yes, it is being executed, I've tested that. The problem is that the include statement does not return a value from the remote script, so I have no way to work with the results locally. Your solution works in that it allows me to run the script locally, but the intention was to run it on the remote server since that is where the files are located and I'm trying to retrieve the file list from there. If you know of an alternative way to accomplish this, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I thought it might be due to missing the php close tags in the echo, but adding those did not help either. In any case, SamGoody's suggestion of using cURL does work, so I'm going with that. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: @Meir: this works, I have just tested it. You must be doing something wrong/different. `file_get_contents`/`curl` are just fetching content from given url, which for your example `Hello World` is ok, but what if you will need to return array? You will need to parse it then. p.s. php file don't need close tags `?>`, [read here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).